# to change class of inputs with same id

Tags: javascript

i want to change similarly class and regarding numbers(among span tags) of all inputs with same id, 
whichever input with same id is clicked. I cannot find a way to achieve this for days, Please help.

```
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_15" class="low"/>(<span id="favoriteX_15" >5</span>)
</div>
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_16" class="medium"/>(<span id="favoriteX_16" >2</span>)
</div>
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_17" class="low"/>(<span id="favoriteX_17" >11</span>)
</div>
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_15" class="low"/>(<span id="favoriteX_15" >5</span>)
</div>
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_18" class="medium"/>(<span id="favoriteX_18" >9</span>)
</div>
div class="something">
<input type="button" id="favorite_18" class="medium"/>(<span id="favoriteX_18" >9</span>)
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".low").click(function(){
        var reference = this;
        var id = this.id;  
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var text = split_id[0];
        var postid = split_id[1];  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'total.php',    
            type: 'post',
            data: {postid:postid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var favoriteX = data;
                $("#favoriteX_"+postid).text(favoriteX);       
                $(reference).removeClass("low"); 
                $(reference).addClass("high"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Already for exaple, input divs which (id="favorite_15")

When I click on first; the number and the class of first changes as it's supposed to be
 but neither class nor number of second  one changes

When I click on second; the number of first changes but second one does not change, the class of second changes but the first one does not :)

Using total.php, i update 'number' value in db, and get current value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique. No two elements must share an `id`. You need to use `class` for this.

Answer (score 0):

just replace :

```
    $(".low").click(function(){
```

with

```
  $('body').on('click', '.low', function(){
```

and try

Comment: its not going to working because both works same in this case. if any element comes dynamic in document then .on() works fine

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should always be unique. make your `ID` to class and check the result.

**The changes I made are:**

1) **Removed duplicate ID and added as a class name** `<input type="button" class="low favorite_15" />`

2) **`var id = this.classList[1];`**, I took the value of **`favorite_15`** from the values of classList.

3) I changed from `ID` to `CLASS` in **`<span class="favoriteX_17">11</span>`**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".low").click(function(){
        var reference = this;
        var id = this.classList[1];  
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var text = split_id[0];
        var postid = split_id[1];  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'total.php',    
            type: 'post',
            data: {postid:postid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var favoriteX = data;
                $(".favoriteX_"+postid).text(favoriteX);       
                $(reference).removeClass("low"); 
                $(reference).addClass("high"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="low favorite_15" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_15">5</span>
)
    </div>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="medium favorite_16" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_16">2</span>
)
    </div>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="low favorite_17" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_17">11</span>
)
    </div>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="low favorite_15" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_15">5</span>
)
    </div>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="medium favorite_18" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_18">9</span>
)
    </div>
    <div class="something">
      <input type="button" class="medium favorite_18" />
(      <span class="favoriteX_18">9</span>
)
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried your proposal, Because of changing id to class, i change in  '$("#favoriteX_"+postid).text(favoriteX);'   ('#' to '.')  Finally, When I click on one of '<input type="button" class="low favorite_15" />'  ,  the number of same class inputs (both of them) change, but class name changes only clicked one so class effects changes on only my clicked

Comment: sorry, '_but class name changes only clicked one so class effects changes on only my clicked_', didnot get this. can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: If i click first <favorite_15> input, only this input's class changes (remove and add) second <favorite_15> input's class does not . When i click second <favorite_15> input, only second input's class changes, first one does not.